# ViewPager OnTouchListener is not called when the inner image have OnTouchListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

When the inner ImageView was not implementing OnTouchListener, viewpager OnTouchListener was being called. When I implemented OnTouchListener in ImageView, ViewPager OnTouchListener is not called anymore. What is the problem?

Comment: onTouch works from top to bottom, now your ImageView is in the front as Viewpager is the container

Comment: so what.. Your viewpager is not getting the touch.. If you can share the code & image of layout then it will be much easier to solve the problem

Comment: My image view is simply this open source one: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java

Comment: so I should dive in this big code ?

Comment: Yes, but for free please :)

Comment: on a serious node share the screen shot of your layout & describe the scenario a bit more clear what actually you want to achieve mean what you want to perform onTouch of ViewPager & what onTouch of imageview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93033/discussion-between-user3441905-and-syed-nazar-muhammad).

Comment: Just don't consume the event in your imageView...

Comment: @SaeedEntezari How not to consume it

Comment: Just return false in your ontouch event